# same file is not being appended to using a singleton reporter class

Tags: java, log4j, singleton

I would like to append to a single file when processes run in my application. Its a very simple requirement for logging type functionality (logging to single file). But I'm not sure why I only get the last appended value in the file. What about the other lines.

In the file output I just see 1 line: "process 2 has Executed". I was expecting to see one corresponding to each of these lines (`executor.execute();`) as shown in main method.

Main method:

```
    public static void main(String args[]){
        ProcessExecutor executor = new ProcessExecutor();
        executor.execute();
        executor.execute();
        executor.execute();

        ProcessExecutorTwo executor2 = new ProcessExecutorTwo();
        executor2.execute();
        executor2.execute();

    }
}
```

Process Executor uses Reporter:

```
// identical to executorOne
public class ProcessExecutorTwo {

private Reporter processTwoReporter; 

    public ProcessExecutorTwo(){
        processTwoReporter = Reporter.getInstance("executor.out");
    }

    public void execute(){
        System.out.println("executing..");
        // .... code taken out
        processTwoReporter.write("process 2 has Executed");
    }
}
```

Reporter class is singleton:

```
public class Reporter {

    private final String headQuartersFile;
    private static Reporter instance;


    private Reporter(String logFile){
        this.headQuartersFile = logFile;
    }

    public static Reporter getInstance(String headQuartersFile){
        synchronized(Reporter.class){
            if(instance==null){
                instance = new Reporter(headQuartersFile);
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void write(String data) {
        PrintWriter out;
        try {
            out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(this.headQuartersFile)), true);
            out.append(data);
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `FileWriter(File file, boolean append)` constructor if you want your `write` method to append to the end of an existing file instead of overwriting it :

```
out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(this.headQuartersFile,true)), true);
```

The `true` flag you already have in your code is in the call to the `PrintWriter` constructor and it has a different purpose (autoFlush).

Comment: what is auto flush for printWriter? shall I remove it?

Comment: And do you think I should use singleton for this?

Comment: Oh and instead of same file, can I use singleton to write to different files?

Comment: @HorseVoice `autoFlush - A boolean; if true, the println, printf, or format methods will flush the output buffer` - if you remove it, the output buffer would be written to the file only when the buffer is full or the file is closed. Since you are writing a single String to the output file before closing it, it would make no difference.

Comment: Thanks. Could you address my other 2 questions about this class being singleton, and can I log multiple files using this singleton class

Comment: @HorseVoice The way your singleton is defined, you can't use multiple files, since the file passed to getInstance would only be used the first time getInstance is called. You could, however, pass the file name as an additional argument to your `write` method.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to understand how logger in java works. Is it an immutable singleton? How does each class get it's own associated log if it's an immutable singleton? If you have time for a chat on this, I would be unbelievably grateful. thank you

Comment: @HorseVoice As for using a singleton, I'm not sure what's the point. Replacing the singleton with a static write method that accepts the file name and the String to append to that file would give you the exact same functionality.

Comment: Hmm, well I was given an assignment in which I have to implement a singleton for my own logger, hence you see the code above. But I was told that java logger is singleton. What functionality would I have to add to my logger so that it warrants the use of a singleton?